# How to post notifications to GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

let me explain my requirement, I want to send a notification to my users on their(Android) when any changes happen on table.

Using SAP NW Gateway I could able to send notification to any listener(listener class)when my table record updated/deleted.

Now I want to send this notification to users android devices,I have seen GCM but not able to understand how can  I post my notification received to GCM and send that message from GCM to Android devices.

Please let me know if I can post my notification details to GCM how to send(read the sent message over GCM) to devices.

Notifications(using SAP Gateway) I am receiving is in XML format.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message, the application server issues a POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Contents of `data` lands on connected GCM clients. Of course, you must first configure GCM API in your google developer's console.

- https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html
- https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Comment: Hi , I tried the same but its throwing 401 unauthorization ..could you please help me to short this.
Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: Hiezaquarii,

It worked,I missed "key=" for the Authorization
Thanks